# Does setting image's source also load the source?

Tags: javascript, html

Say I have the following code:

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = 'https://somePicture.png';
```

Does the image immediately get loaded with the source's data even if I don't append the image to the DOM? In other words, can I make a callback using `img.onload()` that will run even if I don't show the image to the user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, setting the source attribute will load the image.

You can attach a load event to the image, and setting the source attribute if not currently on the page is also the most common approach used when preloading images to prevent tearing on the page during an image swap.

> **4.7.1 The img element**
>
> In a browsing context where scripting is disabled, user agents may obtain images immediately or on demand. In a browsing context where scripting is enabled, user agents must obtain images immediately.
>
> A user agent that obtains images immediately must synchronously update the image data of an img element whenever that element is created with a src attribute. A user agent that obtains images immediately must also synchronously update the image data of an img element whenever that element has its src or crossorigin attribute set, changed, or removed.
>
> https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-img-element